# Evil mode leave insert state if save via I C-x C-s?

Tags: evil

I use evil-mode (specifically in spacemacs) working in org-mode documents. Many times, after evaling code via C-c C-c or exporting via C-c C-e, I find myself saving via C-x C-s (old habits die hard). I then examine output and come back to the document only mangle it because I'm still insert mode.

Added complication: I'm on a chromebook, and I use emacs in a xiwi window, and I tried 
`(add-hook 'focus-out-hook (lambda () (interactive) (evil-normal-state t)))`, but clicking out of the xiwi window into a chromeos window doesn't register the focus-out. :-/

Is there a hook I can plug into so that if I save, I invoke `emacs-normal-state`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, `after-save-hook`. Note that you don't need to call functions following the minor mode conventions with an argument from code to enable something, this allows you to drop the lambda:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'evil-normal-state)
```